# Why was an answer I liked deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Yesterday, I posted a [question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/7964/6697) and got some good answers. One in particular really helped me get the wording on confronting the issue right, but I can't see it, nor can I accept it anymore because it had been deleted (by whom I also don't know).

Why was this particular answer deleted? If it wasn't up to the site standards on Answers, why not?

Comment: The OP deleted it themselves, if you're talking about Tinkeringbell's answer.

Comment: Ah. Hrm, do I just flag the question and try have the answer undeleted, in this case?

Comment: I've pinged her. She may undelete it herself or answer your question here explaining why she removed it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that's the answer I think. Post it?

Answer (score 4):

The answer from anongoodnurse there is basically the same, and has one other very important point: To address the group and not the individual.

I re-read my answer and came to the conclusion it was bad advice, especially when compared to that... I didn't want to leave it around for another person to stumble upon, try and fail horribly. I deleted it because there is better advice there right now.